# Spotify API returning error on models.Search call for Artist "!!!"

Tags: spotify

In our Spotify APP we are making a calling the the model.Search function so we can validate a list of up to 100 artists.  The problem is that one of the artists we might be validating might be something like "!!!".  That is an actual artist name however it causes Spotify to return and error code and empty list for the validated artist names.  We could validate the artist names one-by-one in the app and therefore deal with the error code, however that would greatly slow down the app. Is this a bug in the API? Is Spotify going to fix it anytime soon?  Here is an example of the call we are making:

```
var search = new models.Search("artist:"Mother Love Bone" OR artist:"Hole" OR artist:"Soundgarden" OR     artist:"Stone Temple Pilots" OR artist:"Blind Melon" OR artist:"Silverchair" OR artist:"Alice In Chains" OR     artist:"Bush" OR artist:"Nirvana" OR artist:"Pearl Jam" OR artist:"Big Black" OR artist:"Hüsker Dü" OR     artist:"Throwing Muses" OR artist:"Frank Black" OR artist:"Fugazi" OR artist:"Santogold" OR artist:"This     Mortal Coil" OR artist:"Pixies" OR artist:"Lykke Li" OR artist:"Dinosaur Jr." OR artist:"Dinosaur Jr" OR     artist:"Morphine" OR artist:"Guided By Voices" OR artist:"Spacemen 3" OR artist:"Ride" OR artist:"My     Bloody Valentine" OR artist:"Destroyer" OR artist:"Slowdive" OR artist:"Spiritualized" OR artist:"Wavves"     OR artist:"Joanna Newsom" OR artist:"The Beta Band" OR artist:"The Jon Spencer Blues Explosion" OR     artist:"Jon Spencer Blues Explosion" OR artist:"Death From Above 1979" OR artist:"Buzzcocks" OR     artist:"The Buzzcocks" OR artist:"Television" OR artist:"Battles" OR artist:"Morrissey" OR artist:"The Stone     Roses" OR artist:"Ian Brown" OR artist:"The Libertines" OR artist:"The Psychedelic Furs" OR     artist:"Psychedelic Furs" OR artist:"Kings Of Convenience" OR artist:"Happy Mondays" OR artist:"Yo La     Tengo" OR artist:"Echo & The Bunnymen" OR artist:"The Specials" OR artist:"Interpol" OR artist:"Yeah     Yeah Yeahs" OR artist:"Doves" OR artist:"Dover" OR artist:"Joy Division" OR artist:"Silver Jews" OR     artist:"!!!"");
search.localResults = models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.IGNORE;
search.searchArtists = true;
search.searchAlbums = false;
search.searchTracks = false;
search.searchPlaylists = false;
search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() { ... });
search.observe(models.EVENT.LOAD_ERROR, function() { // We got error here });
search.appendNext();
```

Comment: err, tried to make that a code block and it failed

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate that in the web API's search (all I have access to). "!!!" doesn't return any results, but it doesn't return an error either.

Maybe try url-encoding it? That would turn "!!!" into "%21%21%21". It doesn't make any difference in the web API - still returns no results but no error. But it's possible there's an encoding glitch specific to the main API.